# objectMapper converting hindi text into special charactor "???"

Tags: java, spring-mvc, objectmapper

I'm storing Hindi in database.
In my fetch method I'm using `objectMapper` which is converting Hindi font into special character. without `objectmapper` it's working fine.

```
@CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> fetchDepartmentInfo() {
        try {
            List<Map<String, Object>> departmentList = departmentServices.fetchDepartments();

            if (departmentList == null || departmentList.isEmpty())
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            else
                return new ResponseEntity<String>(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(departmentList), HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

o/p:

```
[
    {
        "department": "?? ?? ?????",
        "departmentId": 1
    }
]
```

but it should be:

```
[
    {
        "department": "जल कल विभाग",
        "departmentId": 1
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you sure that this the corruption happens during serializing to string and not during reading the input? First check using debugger that `departmentList` contains correct values.

Comment: when i removed objectmapper it will return expected result. so yes its problem with objectmapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just changed mediaType to `APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE`

```
@CrossOrigin
        @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity<?> fetchDepartmentInfo() {
            try {
                List<Map<String, Object>> departmentList = departmentServices.fetchDepartments();

                if (departmentList == null || departmentList.isEmpty())
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
                else
                    return new ResponseEntity<String>(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(departmentList), HttpStatus.OK);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }
```

it resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can enable pretty-print configuring the indentation your Jackson mapper: `mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);` and this should do the conversion correctly.

Checking [documentation](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html) for SerializationFeature:

> Feature that allows enabling (or disabling) indentation for the
>   underlying generator, using the default pretty printer (see
>   JsonGenerator.useDefaultPrettyPrinter() for details).